# Udacity python exercise

Tags: python

Im coding a madlibs exercise and it is not returning the desired outcome. It should replace the words NOUN and VERB with random verbs and nouns that are defined in the functions in the code.

I have created two test sentences and after running the code I only get the first character of both sentences. I cant think for the life of me why!!

```
from random import randint

def random_verb():
    random_num = randint(0, 1)
    if random_num == 0:
        return "run"
    else:
        return "kayak"

def random_noun():
    random_num = randint(0,1)
    if random_num == 0:
        return "sofa"
    else:
        return "llama"

def word_transformer(word):
    if word == "NOUN":
        return random_noun()
    elif word == "VERB":
        return random_verb()
    else:
        return word[0]

def process_madlib(madlib):
    #the finished sentence
    processed = ""
    #starting point
    index = 0
    #length to cut from
    box_length = 4
    #
    while index<len(madlib):
        #what you cut off from string
        frame = madlib[index:index+box_length]
        #put to string
        to_add = word_transformer(frame)
        processed += to_add
        if len(to_add) == 1:
            index +=1
        else:
            index +=5
        return processed
    # your code here
    # you may find the built-in len function useful for this quiz
    # documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len

test_string_1 = "This is a good NOUN to use when you VERB your food"
test_string_2 = "I'm going to VERB to the store and pick up a NOUN or two."
print process_madlib(test_string_1)
print process_madlib(test_string_2)
```

the outcome is

T 
I

Comment: What output do you expect ? Can you elaborate a bit about it

Answer (score 0):

Your return is not correctly placed.
The `return processed` is inside the `while` loop - so after the first iteration of your while loop you will always return the value - which is just the first letter in the sentence.

You need to place it outside.

```
def process_madlib(madlib):
    #the finished sentence
    processed = ""
    #starting point
    index = 0
    #length to cut from
    box_length = 4
    #
    while index<len(madlib):
        #what you cut off from string
        frame = madlib[index:index+box_length]
        #put to string
        to_add = word_transformer(frame)
        processed += to_add
        if len(to_add) == 1:
            index +=1
        else:
            index +=5
    return processed  # <---- THIS IS WHAT WAS CHANGED
```

This gives the output:

```
This is a good sofato use when you runyour food
I'm going to kayakto the store and pick up a llamaor two.
```